# delete_transient on click inside a widget form

Tags: transient

I'd like to use `transient` for my widget. User can choose for how long data can be cached (1, 2, 10 hours). I also want to add a button `Refresh now` inside a widget form.

I don't know how to call `delete_transient` on click.

I was thinking to create some hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="refresh-data" value="0" />`). Set `1` if the button was clicked. Check it inside `function widget()` and call `delete_transient` if needed. But I think I can't set `0` to `refresh-data` inside `widget` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the widget and the "Refresh now" button are shown on the front-end, yes? One option to delete a transient is to use ajax to do it.

This is rather rough example, but I hope it gives you the idea what to do. You can read more about Ajax in WordPress from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

```
// In your php file
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_delete_transient_action', 'my_delete_transient_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_delete_transient_action', 'my_delete_transient_action' ); // for users that are not logged in

function my_delete_transient_action() {

    // Check nonce and other stuff here as needed
    // If and when everything is ok, then use the delete_transient function
    $deleted = delete_transient('my_user_specific_transient'); // returns bool

    // Option 1 to send custom text response back to front-end
    if ($deleted) {
        echo 'Transient deleted';
    } else {
        echo 'Transient deletion failed';
    } 
    die();

    // Option 2
    if ($deleted) {
        wp_send_json_success('Transient deleted');
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Transient deletion failed');
    }

}

// In your js file
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.my-reset-button').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            'action': 'my_delete_transient_action',
        };

        // You can use wp_localize_script in php file to have admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) available in front-end
        jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response); // do something with the response
        });
    });
});
```